# Need Left Outer Join in LINQ using Extension Method /Query Syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

i have a schema with the following structure;
[image]

Basically, a menu can have nested childs. And the other tables just holds `ItemType`, and the Id of the that item i.e `ItemTypeId` (these are referenced dynamically when user choos options at backend).
Now, for menus to be displayed, i have used **Inner Join** (i want here to use **Left Outer Join**) here;

```
public IQueryable<Menu> GetMenuWithAsset()
{
    return DbContext.Set<Menu>()
                    .Join(DbContext.Set<Asset>(), m => m.MenuId, a => a.MenuId, (m, a) => m);
}
```

and in my base controller, i'm fetching it like this;

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var menus = Uow.Menus.GetMenuWithAsset()

        .Select(m => new ParentMenuViewModel()
        {
            MenuId = m.MenuId,
            Name = m.Name,
            ParentId = m.ParentId
        })
        .ToList<ParentMenuViewModel>();
    ViewBag.Menus = CreateVM(0, menus);
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}

public IEnumerable<ParentMenuViewModel> CreateVM(int parentid, List<ParentMenuViewModel> list)
{
    var newList = list.Where(m=> m.ParentId==parentid)
        .Select(m=> new ParentMenuViewModel()
        {
            MenuId = m.MenuId,
            Name = m.Name,
            ParentId = m.ParentId,
            ChildMenus = CreateVM(m.MenuId, list)
        });
    return newList;
}
```

And this code works correctly as expected. However, here is what i want;
**1) I want to display all the menus(including child menus) whetere we have data or not in `Asset` table ( i gess left outer join). 

2) I want to achieve this using strongly typed viewmodel which will hold the following properties from both of the tables 

i) MenuId ii) Name iii)ParentId iv) ChildMenus v)MenuItemType vi) MenuItemTypeId**
I'm trying to solve this from 4 days. Any help regard to this is apreciatable;

Comment: Why do you need it to be "Extension Method Syntax"? It just makes it harder to read in most cases.

Comment: ok, if you can, it is also acceptable in query syntax

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
DbContext.Set<Menu>()
         .GroupJoin(DbContext.Set<Asset>(), m => m.MenuId, a => a.MenuId, (m, as) => new { m, as = as.DefaultIfEmpty() });
```

It will return anonymus class with property m of type Menu and property as that contains IQueriable of Assets. I hope this is what you want.

Comment: getting error near @ `a.DefaultIfEmpty()` Error 1 Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.